# How are fragments destroyed which are created with fragmentstateadapter (viewpager2)

Tags: android-fragments, kotlin, android-room, android-livedata, android-viewpager2

In a static (3 pages) ViewPager2 setup where the ViewPager2 is situated in a fragment, I have created 3 fragments in the FragmentStateAdapter descendant. I have even collected the fragments in a table ( `MutableList<Fragment> = Vector<Fragment>()`) in that descendant for later reference. The `offscreenPageLimit` is set to `3`, so the fragments will not die, but only resumed and paused.

One fragment is a map, one fragment is a table setup with several livedata references (room based), a third will be a picture page.

When leaving this ViewPager2 fragment, and recycling the room database (refreshing contents) my app crashed... it occured to me that the three fragments created in the FragmentStateAdapter descendant wasn't destroyed (of course ?)(a nulled database couldn't be handled by the fragment), because there wasn't any way the FragmentStateAdapter would kill those fragments. Of course I could kill them in the FragmentStateAdapter descendant, but aren't there any simple way to handle those deaths ?

Much of the code below is template based, so some may be unnecessary

Code extract:

AddStationFragment:

```
class AddStationFragment : Fragment() {
// TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
private var param1: String? = null
private var param2: String? = null
private var listener: OnFragmentInteractionListener? = null

private val TAG by lazy { this::class.java.simpleName }

private lateinit var adRequest: AdRequest

private lateinit var binding: FragmentAddStationBinding

private lateinit var viewModel: AddStationViewModel

var fragments: MutableList<Fragment> = Vector<Fragment>()

lateinit var addStationFragmentStateAdapter: AddStationFragmentStateAdapter

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    Log.i(TAG,"fra: onCreate()")
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    arguments?.let {
        param1 = it.getString(ARG_PARAM1)
        param2 = it.getString(ARG_PARAM2)
    }
}

override fun onResume() {
    Log.i(TAG,"fra: onResume()")
    super.onResume()

    activity?.let {activity->
        activity.fab?.let { fab ->
            fab.hide()
            fab.setImageDrawable(resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_baseline_check_24, context?.theme))
            fab.clearAnimation()
            //fab.isEnabled = false

            fab.setOnClickListener { view ->
                Log.i(TAG,"fab.clicked !")
            }

            //fab.show()
        }

        (activity as MainActivity).setOptionsMenu(OptionsMenuSet.ADDSTATION)
        activity.bottom_navigation.visibility=View.GONE

        listener?.registerFragment(this)
    }

}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

    Log.i(TAG,"fra: onViewCreated")

    val tabtext = arrayOf(
        "Location",
        "Address",
        "Enterprise")

    val iconresource = arrayOf(
        R.drawable.ic_add_location_black_24dp,
        R.drawable.ic_info_outline_black_24dp,
        R.drawable.ic_baseline_business_24)

    TabLayoutMediator(
        binding.addStationTabLayout,
        binding.addStationViewPager2,
        TabLayoutMediator.TabConfigurationStrategy { tab: TabLayout.Tab, position: Int ->
            tab.text = tabtext[position]
            tab.setIcon(iconresource[position])
            tab.icon?.let { icon ->
                DrawableCompat.setTint(
                    icon,
                    ContextCompat.getColor(activity as Context, R.color.cardBG_lightred))
            }
            /*tab.icon?.setColorFilter(
                ContextCompat.getColor(activity as Context, R.color.cardBG_lightred),
                PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN)*/ //Deprecated


        }
    ).attach()



    //super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
}

override fun onDestroy() {
    Log.i(TAG,"fra: onDestroy()")

    Log.i(TAG,"fra: Childfragment size: ${childFragmentManager.fragments.size}")



    super.onDestroy()
}


override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    Log.i(TAG,"fra: onCreateView()")

    binding = FragmentAddStationBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)

    context?:return binding.root

    adRequest = AdRequest.Builder().build()

    binding.addStationAdView.loadAd(adRequest)

    addStationFragmentStateAdapter = AddStationFragmentStateAdapter(
        activity?:return binding.root,fragments)

    binding.addStationViewPager2.offscreenPageLimit = 3
    binding.addStationViewPager2.adapter = addStationFragmentStateAdapter

    val factory = InjectorUtils.provideAddStationViewModelFactory(context?:return binding.root)
    viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, factory).get(AddStationViewModel::class.java)

    viewModel.liveNewStationForUser.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { station ->
        Log.i(TAG,"onCreateView liveNewStationForUser station = $station")
    })

    AddStationRepository.createTemplate("")

    return binding.root
}

// TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
fun onButtonPressed(uri: Uri) {
    listener?.onFragmentInteraction(uri)
}

override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
    Log.i(TAG,"fra: onAttach()")
    super.onAttach(context)
    if (context is OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
        listener = context
    } else {
        throw RuntimeException(context.toString() + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener")
    }
}

override fun onPause() {
    Log.i(TAG,"fra: onPause()")
    super.onPause()
}

override fun onDetach() {
    Log.i(TAG,"fra: onDetach()")
    super.onDetach()
    listener = null
}

/**
 * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
 * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
 * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
 * activity.
 *
 *
 * See the Android Training lesson [Communicating with Other Fragments]
 * (http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html)
 * for more information.
 */
interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    // TODO: Update argument type and name
    fun onFragmentInteraction(uri: Uri)
    fun registerFragment(fragment: Fragment)
    fun unregisterFragment(fragment: Fragment)
}

companion object {
    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment AddStationFragment.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    @JvmStatic
    fun newInstance(param1: String, param2: String) =
        AddStationFragment().apply {
            arguments = Bundle().apply {
                putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1)
                putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2)
            }
        }
}
}
```

---

AddStationFragmentStateAdapter: (descendant of FragmentStateAdapter)

```
class AddStationFragmentStateAdapter(
fragmentActivity: FragmentActivity,
private val fragmentList: MutableList<Fragment>
) :
FragmentStateAdapter(fragmentActivity) {

private val TAG by lazy {this::class.java.simpleName}

override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment {

    Log.i(TAG, "createFragment position = $position")

    val fragment: Fragment = when (position) {
        0 -> FragmentAddStationMap()
        1 -> FragmentAddStationInfo()
        else -> FragmentAddStationEnterprise()
    }

    if (fragmentList.size <= position)
        fragmentList.add(fragment)
    else
        fragmentList[position] = fragment

    Log.i(TAG, "fra: fragmentList.size = ${fragmentList.size}")

    return fragment
}



override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    Log.i(TAG,"fra: fragmentListSize = ${fragmentList.size}")
    return 3
}

}
```

So... what is your suggestion I should do in the `onDestroy()` for the `AddStationFragment`, I have checked the `childFragmentManager`, but there aren't any fragments there (as I should expect, since I provided the `fragmentActivity` in the `FragmentStateAdapter` call (in the `FragmentStateAdapter` descendant `AddStationFragmentStateAdapter`), where are they seated, and who (and how) should (I) destroy them the best way ?

RG

Answer (score 4):

Instead of passing the `activity` to the `FragmentStateAdapter`'s constructor you should pass the parent `Fragment`.

```
class MainPagerAdapter(fragment: MyParentFragment) : FragmentStateAdapter(fragment) {}
```

When the parent fragment is destroyed the viewpager's fragments will also be destroyed.

Answer (score 1):

I actually found an answer for my question, not directly, but a workaround that might help others too with same problem.

A. In the `FragmentStateAdapter` descendandt (i.e. `AddStationFragmentStateAdapter`) change the "artificial" `fragmentList` to `public`, so you can reach it from outside.

B. then in the `onDestroy()` method of the `ViewPager2`'s fragment (i.e. `AddStationFragment`) iterate through the public `fragmentList` and call `fragment.parentFragmentManager.beginTransaction().remove(fragment).commit()`

"B" will release the fragment from the list it resides on, and everything is tidy and clean...

codechanges:

---

In AddStationFragmentStateAdapter we set the fragmentList public:

```
class AddStationFragmentStateAdapter(
 fragmentActivity: FragmentActivity,
 public var fragmentList: MutableList<Fragment>  //changed to public
) :
FragmentStateAdapter(fragmentActivity) {

private val TAG by lazy {this::class.java.simpleName}
...
```

and in AddStationFragment onDestroy():

```
override fun onDestroy() {
    Log.i(TAG,"fra: onDestroy()")

    Log.i(TAG,"fra: Childfragment size: ${childFragmentManager.fragments.size}")

    Log.i(TAG,"fra: addStationFragmentStateAdapter.fragmentList.size = ${addStationFragmentStateAdapter.fragmentList.size}")

    addStationFragmentStateAdapter.fragmentList.forEach { fragment:Fragment ->
        fragment.parentFragmentManager.beginTransaction().remove(fragment).commit()
    }

    super.onDestroy()
}
```

RG